# Setting up permissions to allow ASP.net code behind to create folders on Server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, file-upload, directory

I have an ASP.net website that will allow users to upload images using a third party webHTMLEditor. I have the overall folder created and the editor finds it but when I try to dynamically create a user specific folder it throws "WinIOError. Access to the path '../common/upload/1' is denied."

I'm not very familiar with setting up permissions and IIS on the server side so I was hoping someone could run me through how to give ASP.net code behind the ability to create the numbered folder portion of the "../common/upload/1" path.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.

Comment: I was able to figure it out from the artical dmarietta linked and trial and error. It turns out I needed to do two things, first was set up the IUSR account to have write permissions second was to seperate out the string that was used as the directory pointer and the one that was given to the editor for its upload destination path. the editor was altering the string that was beign passed in as the upload location without giving any feedback. gotta love third party tools...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the proper filesystem level permissions for the user context the site is running in. So if this is a site open to random visitors, you would look at the settings for your anonymous user account (IUSR). If you are requiring user authentication, then you would need to set the permissions based on the user or group(s) they belong to. Note, your filesystem permissions pertain to the same permissions as if you are configuring for file access on a server for a user on your network/machine. Thus this is not the same thing as the IIS server access permissions, so to make sure you are not looking at the wrong permissions, do not use IIS manager.

The following article may help with some more specific details:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/583/secure-content-in-iis-through-file-system-acls/

Comment: Do not let the anonymous user do something like this.

Comment: @IrishChieftain - If the CODE that is being executed on the website needs to create/remove folders, this is necessary for the application to work and there is nothing wrong with doing that - provided it is a well written application. Maybe should have elaborated that point above, but then again if you don't trust the application you are writing/installing on your server to use the proper permissions, then it should not be used on the server in the first place.

Comment: Just saying if it was badly written, it could bring the server down ;-)

Comment: in order for them to get this far in the application they would be a paying customer of ours and the customer ID is set by us so there wont be duplicates or anything like that.  this is also completely controled by the program and the folder is only attempted to be created once obviously. Its not like they can type in whatever they want and the website is trying to make a correlating file. I read through that link and added IUSR to the list of users that had read/write permissions to the associated folder but still giving me the same error.