# How to give permission to dynamically created folders to save files in them in asp.net from c# code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, io

I  am trying to create a safe file transfer system and in my file server I have a webservice which receives an array of files and will create some directories and subdirectories according to parameters like the users username who has uploaded the files and datetime of file uploading . So here is the issue :

1 - I have to create folders and sub folders dynamically and per request and I am able to create folders

2 - I want to save each file in It's directory after creating the mentioned folders

3 - When I try to save files using following code I get the `Access is denied`  error message

```
                    string RootSavePath = @"C:\SFTFileSharingFolder";
                    string RequestSavePath = RootSavePath + "\\Date " + getShamsiDate().Replace("/", "-") + " Time " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
                    if (!Directory.Exists(RequestSavePath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(RequestSavePath);
                    }
                    fl.SaveAs(RequestSavePath);
```

fl is Id of the FileUpload Control

What I want to know :

**Is there any way to give permission to current user and application on dynamically created folders
from c# code behind So the files would be saved with no error ?**

Comment: can you Update the  question with your code ?

Comment: @Damith I updated the question and put the code

Comment: what is `f1`? how you get the file name of new file?

Comment: @Damith Question is edited , fl is the FileUpload Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Web application runs under a certain account (and not doing impersonation), all you need to do is grant that account Full Access to the folder where your code will be creating subfolders.

If you are using impersonation, that means the code runs under the account of the authenticated user. In that case, you have to grant all users access to that folder -- or rather, the Active Directory group that you use for authorizing access.

Comment: Is not there any heirarcy level limitation ? I mean if I want to create 3 level of subfolders inside that folder ?

Comment: If your code creates those 3 subfolders, fine. If you create them manually, you may have to grant Full Access rights again to the main folder, **including all subfolders** if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: for testing what you said I published the app on my local IIS and I created the rootfolder and applied full permission on that folder for IIS_User and I clicked on  advanced button and checked the checkbox  :  the Replace all child object permissions with ... but I steel get that error :( am I doing any thing wrong ?

Comment: I hosted the webbapp in IIS ! and I applied permission to IIS_User

Comment: There is an easy test to see whether you have the account right or wrong. Simply give (temporarily!) the group "Everyone" full access to that folder and try again. If it works now, you have given permission earlier to the wrong user.

Comment: So you are running this on a developer PC, you gave Everyone full access to that folder including subfolders, and still it doesn't work? So did you add <YourMachine>\Everyone or <YourDomain>\Everyone? Try them both and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think because the IIS server was not configured correctly. I think there is your place to find out an answer [Setting up permissions to allow ASP.net code behind to create folders on Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653606/setting-up-permissions-to-allow-asp-net-code-behind-to-create-folders-on-server)

Answer (score 0):

Give modification rights for the parent directory on the drive which you create the folders to user who running your web application/ app pool

```
string RootSavePath = @"C:\SFTFileSharingFolder";
var serverPath = Path.Combine(RootSavePath , "Date " + getShamsiDate().Replace("/", "-") +
                " Time " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "." +
                DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "." + 
                DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());

if (!Directory.Exists(serverPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(serverPath);
}

fl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(serverPath, f1.FileName);
```

Comment: I want to save the file in another drive or folder rather than the application folder !